# Suppress commit-message template with `git merge --squash` or `--no-commit`

Tags: git

When using `git merge` with an option that suppresses automatic committing (`--no-commit` or `--squash`), `git` apparently always generates its own template for the next commit message; the next `git commit` ignores the `-t` option. Is there anyway to suppress this?

The best workaround I've found is to use `-m` with the commit, then immediately run `git commit --amend`. This seems awkward to me, though, and it removes the ability to abort the commit by deleting the commit message template before saving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inspected contents of `.git` directory after doing `git merge --squash` you would see `SQUASH_MSG` file that contains a commit message template. This file is also created after doing a squash with `git rebase -i`. You need to remove this file if you don't want Git to populate commit message automatically when doing `git commit`. If would be useful to alias a native `git commit` command to do this automatically for you but it's not [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias) with Git. Instead, we should create an alias like this in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
         kommit = "!KOMIT_GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); if [ -a "${KOMIT_GIT_DIR}/SQUASH_MSG" ] ; then rm "${KOMIT_GIT_DIR}/SQUASH_MSG" ; fi && git commit"
```

This line checks whether SQUASH_MSG exists and removes if it does before doing `git commit`. Now you should do `git komit` instead of `git commit` after performing `git merge --squash`.

I tested this with Git 2.3.1:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.3.1
```

Comment: Awesome. I actually wanted this to be part of a more extensive alias I'm writing anyway, so I don't mind that you can't alias over `commit` itself. I'll let you know if this works for my version (`1.7.10.4`).

Comment: Note that your quotes surrounding variables should be escaped...

Comment: Yep, `SQUASH_MSG` is exactly what I wanted. I ended up just writing over it with my preferred template instead of deleting it.

Comment: For future readers who might not want to make an alias: this can also be done using a `pre-commit` hook. Just add the same lines of code excluding `&& git commit` into the hook and now it works with `git commit` as well.